# api gateway cannot handle queryparameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a service which accepts the following query params format:

?pid=1&pid=2&pid=3

Now the problem is api gateway cannot handle it and only returns last one which is pid=3. So I am thinking by the use of body template mapping this might be possible. SO in method request I have:

[image]

In integration request I have:

[image]

and in the bodymapping section of itegration request I add:
[image]

Now when I test it the mapping does not work and api gate way instead of asking for the pid1 and pid2 and pid3 will ask for everything which is a default behavior when there is no query params sent to the service.
Is it possible at all? Or is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: have you tried to change the name of the, in the template? It is always pid? :D

Comment: u mean instead of pid I set it as id?

Comment: `{ 'pid1':$input.params('pid1'); 'pid2':$input.params('pid2'); }`

Comment: @BAD_SEED But this what I want to feed the http url query string: pid=1&pid=2&pid=3 that is why I seit them all with pid. I want to attach pid=1&pid=2&pid=3  to the http endpoit of integration request.

Comment: But pid can't have three value. Just one, the last, i.e. 3

Comment: @BAD_SEED Yeah in apigateway yes but in my service written in rest java jersey it will accept this url?pid=1&pid=2 as a list of pids and can handle it